# Object Reference Not Set to Instance of an Object in Google Cloud Loadobject

Tags: bigdata, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

```
`loadconfig.SourceUris.Add(@"gs:\\planar-fulcrum-837\leadload-ip\01-         
 02-2013");`
```

Null object reference set to instance of an object

Comment: I'm not sure what's being asked here...

Comment: I am trying to load .csv files from google cloud onto big query table. so i am using .net cloud and big query libraries for the same to load cloud .csv files to bq.   Alternatively if someone could suggest how to insert MULTIPLE .CSV files from cloud to big query...USING big query LOAD command line utility

Comment: Why not ask this in the first place? Also, why the obscure title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working sample for loading CSV file from cloud storage into Google Big Query.

Update variables such as "ServiceAccountEmail, KeyFileName, KeySecret, ProjectID, Dataset name and etc..

Add your table schema into this variable

```
TableSchema Schema = new TableSchema();
```

Here i am using single file loading, you can add N number of CSV file into this variable

```
System.Collections.Generic.IList<string> URIs = newSystem.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
URIs.Add(filePath);
```

Use this below code modify & work with it. Have a great day. (This solution i have found working more than 3 days).

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2;
using Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data;
using System.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace GoogleBigQuery
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                String serviceAccountEmail = "SERVICE ACCOUNT EMAIL";

                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"KEY FILE NAME & PATH", "KEY SECRET", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

                // SYNTAX: var certificate=new X509Certificate2(KEY FILE PATH+NAME (Here it resides in Bin\Debug folder so only name is enough), SECRET KEY, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

                ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                   new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                   {
                       Scopes = new[] { BigqueryService.Scope.Bigquery, BigqueryService.Scope.BigqueryInsertdata, BigqueryService.Scope.CloudPlatform, BigqueryService.Scope.DevstorageFullControl }
                   }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                //  Create and initialize the Bigquery service. Use the Project Name value
                //  from the New Project window for the ApplicationName variable.

                BigqueryService Service = new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "APPLICATION NAME"
                });

                TableSchema Schema = new TableSchema();

                TableFieldSchema F1 = new TableFieldSchema();
                F1.Name = "COLUMN NAME";
                F1.Type = "STRING";
                F1.Mode = "REQUIRED";

                TableFieldSchema F2 = new TableFieldSchema();
                F1.Name = "COLUMN NAME";
                F1.Type = "INTEGER";
                F1.Mode = "NULLABLE";

                //Add N number of fields as per your needs

                System.Collections.Generic.IList<TableFieldSchema> FS = new System.Collections.Generic.List<TableFieldSchema>();
                FS.Add(F1);
                FS.Add(F2);

                Schema.Fields = FS;

                JobReference JR = JobUpload("PROJECT ID", "DATASET NAME", "TABLE NAME", @"gs://BUCKET NAME/FILENAME", Schema, "CREATE_IF_NEEDED", "WRITE_APPEND", '|', Service);

                //SYNTAX JobReference JR = JobUpload(PROJECT ID, DATASET NAME, TABLE NAME, FULL PATH OF CSV FILE,FILENAME IN CLOUD STORAGE, TABLE SCHEMA, CREATE DISPOSITION, DELIMITER, BIGQUERY SERVICE);

                while (true)
                {
                    var PollJob = Service.Jobs.Get(JR.ProjectId, JR.JobId).Execute();

                    Console.WriteLine("Job status" + JR.JobId + ": " + PollJob.Status.State);
                    if (PollJob.Status.State.Equals("DONE"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("JOB Completed");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error Occurred: " + e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static JobReference JobUpload(string project, string dataset, string tableId, string filePath, TableSchema schema, string createDisposition, string writeDisposition, char delimiter, BigqueryService BigQueryService)
        {

            TableReference DestTable = new TableReference();
            DestTable.ProjectId = project;
            DestTable.DatasetId = dataset;
            DestTable.TableId = tableId;

            Job Job = new Job();
            JobConfiguration Config = new JobConfiguration();
            JobConfigurationLoad ConfigLoad = new JobConfigurationLoad();

            ConfigLoad.Schema = schema;
            ConfigLoad.DestinationTable = DestTable;
            ConfigLoad.Encoding = "ISO-8859-1";
            ConfigLoad.CreateDisposition = createDisposition;
            ConfigLoad.WriteDisposition = writeDisposition;
            ConfigLoad.FieldDelimiter = delimiter.ToString();
            ConfigLoad.AllowJaggedRows = true;
            ConfigLoad.SourceFormat = "CSV";
            ConfigLoad.SkipLeadingRows = 1;
            ConfigLoad.MaxBadRecords = 100000;

            System.Collections.Generic.IList<string> URIs = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
            URIs.Add(filePath);

            //You can add N number of CSV Files here

            ConfigLoad.SourceUris = URIs;
            Config.Load = ConfigLoad;
            Job.Configuration = Config;

            //set job reference (mainly job id)
            JobReference JobRef = new JobReference();
            Random r = new Random();
            var JobNo = r.Next();
            JobRef.JobId = "Job" + JobNo.ToString();
            JobRef.ProjectId = project;
            Job.JobReference = JobRef;

            JobsResource.InsertRequest InsertMediaUpload = new JobsResource.InsertRequest(BigQueryService, Job, Job.JobReference.ProjectId);
            var JobInfo = InsertMediaUpload.Execute();

            return JobRef;
        }
    }
}
```